# $ionicScrollDelegate locks the view on the scrolled value

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I'm getting the list of results in my cordova app, i want to roll it to the specified element with this function:

```
    $scope.roll = function () {
        //var rankScroll = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('rank');

        var meElement = document.getElementById('scroll');
        if (!meElement) {
            $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(0, 0);
            return;
        }

        var top = meElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - 50;
        $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(0, top);
        console.log(top);
        console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView());

    }
```

It works nicely, but I can't scroll to any other place in the list. I want to unlock scrolling in this solution or find better one. It should scroll on page loaded, not on click.

All the best

Comment: removing the <ion-scroll> wrapper helped, but affected the smoothenss of scrolling

Answer (score 0):

That function lock your scroll because of the $scope's binding.

If you only want that function to be invoked when the view is loaded, you should call it once at the the time the view is loaded.

You can do that by this way in your controller:

```
var roll = function () {
    //var rankScroll = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('rank');

    var meElement = document.getElementById('scroll');
    if (!meElement) {
        $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(0, 0);
        return;
    }

    var top = meElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - 50;
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(0, top);
    console.log(top);
    console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollView());

}
$scope.$on("$ionicView.loaded", function (scopes, states) {
    roll();
});
```

You can check more $ionicView events in this [ion-view Document](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)